# How to wait for RequestQueue job to finish?

Tags: android, get, nonblocking

I'm trying to create a login page for my app. I check the credentials by doing a get request to a web server which is tied in to my user database.

```
public boolean checkCredentials(String email, String password) throws JSONException {

    // Make a get request to the server
    String url = MyUtils.createLoginUrl(email, password);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, requestParam, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    successLogin = response.length() > 0;
                    jsonResponse = response.length() > 0 ? response : null;
                    //requestPending -= 1;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    MyUtils.showToast(getBaseContext(), error.getMessage().toString());
                    //requestPending -= 1;
                }
            });

    SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    //requestPending += 1;
    // I WANT THE JOB TO FINISH BEFORE RETURNING FROM THIS FUNCTION
    return successLogin;
}
```

Is there a non-blocking way to do this using the Volley library? Google wasn't giving me much info.

Comment: What you mean by saying 'non-blocking way' ? make it more clear.

Comment: I think he wants to return the status of the login before finishing the method.  By the nature of the authentication you propose, you will need to wait for some unknown time before returning your boolean.  You should simply create another method that is called on success that communicates to any interested classes that the auth was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with Volley and you shoudn't with other tools. Long running operations like going to database or to network block the UI thread which is a bad practice since the user can't interact to the UI.

Talking about volley, it does all this job asynchronous in three thread levels:

- UI
- Cache
- Network

See [here](http://www.programering.com/images/remote/ZnJvbT1jbmJsb2dzJnVybD0yVWpOd0VUT3dNVE01SVRPd01UTXdJekwwVm1idTRHWnpObUxuOUdiaTV5WnRsMkx2b0RjMFJIYQ.jpg) the schema.
All three levels allows the system to cache the responses and use a pool thread to dispatch all the requests at the same time if enough space and memory.

Some time ago people recommended you to do:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

This avoided the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, but as I told you before it is a really ***bad practice*** because you will be skipping a bunch of frames by waiting.
I know listeners are a pain, but all we have to live with them in Android Dev.